# Windows 10 color issue after update

Tags: windows, windows-10, colors, updates, bug

Today I updated windows 10 and since the windows started again , colors are all darker . I disabled some options in Task Scheduler and it worked for a an hour but again , everything is going dark . GPU driver is the latest for geforce 1070 ti card . It's really messing up with my eyes . what should I do ?

Comment: Have you tried (a) different themes; (b) light and dark settings; (c) color calibration settings - All in Windows 10 settings?

Comment: could it be night mode?  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/set-your-display-for-night-time-in-windows-10-18fe903a-e0a1-8326-4c68-fd23d7aaf136

Comment: yeah it was the night mode actually ! thanks for the answer .

Comment: A comment isn’t an answer nor should it be considered to be one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like it might be Windows 10 Night Mode.  This function allows you to reduce the amount of blue light emitted from your monitor.

More information on Night Mode can be found [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/set-your-display-for-night-time-in-windows-10-18fe903a-e0a1-8326-4c68-fd23d7aaf136).